Value changes during return from module function in Powershell
I have a simple function in a module:
NumberOfFoldersInDir($pathToDir, $_isRecursive)
This module is used by a class within another module. I return a value, depending on the optional bool param _isRecursive:
if($_isRecursive) { return (1) }; else { return (2) }
1) (Get-ChildItem -Path $pathToDir -Directory -Recurse).Count
2) (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory).Count
In the module, when I save to a variable and write-host, values are:
1) == 2
2) == 1

Directory Structure:

Why in the world would a value ever change after being returned when it is using exactly the same code to get to the value?

Can you post a complete example that reproduces the behavior?

https://github.com/staspk/OS-Setup/tree/main/Windows11, will edit post with a bit more info

Oh, I see what you mean now. That's easy: $path is not $pathToDir - fix that, and you'll get the correct counts (because you'll actually be looking in $pathToDir instead of your current folder)

Wow I feel dumb. Changing it up over and over must have messed with my mind. Thank you Mathias.

Why are your counting two times? (on line 61/62 and on 75/77)  (screenshot from Kozubenko.Utils.psm:  https://i.sstatic.net/CU5GthEr.png )

@Luuk Just for debugging purposes. Mathias found the issue though. Amazing how quickly a pair of fresh eyes can find a stupid bug, while I've been confounded for several hours.
